# Regex to remove all non alpha-numeric and replace spaces with +

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to use regex to try remove all non alpha-numeric characters from a string and replace spaces with a +

All I want to permit is basically alphabetical words A-Z and +

**This is specifically to prepare the string to become a part of a URL, thus need the + symbols instead of spaces.**

I have looked at `/\W+/` however this removes all white spaces and alpha-numeric characters, whereas I want to leave the spaces in if possible to then be replaced by + symbols.

I've searched around a bit but I can't seem to find something, I was hoping someone might have any simple suggestions for this.

**Sample string & Desired result:**
`Durarara!!x2 Ten` **->** durarara+x2+ten

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is actually fairly straightforward.

Assuming `str` is the string you're cleaning up:

```
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, '+');
```

The `^` means "anything not in this list of characters". The `+` after the `[...]` group means "one or more". `/gi` means "replace all of these that you find, without regard to case".

So any stretch of characters that are not letters, numbers, or '+' will be converted into a single '+'.

To remove parenthesized substrings (as requested in the comments), do this replacement first:

```
str = str.replace(/\(.+?\)/g, '');
```

```js
function replacer() {

  var str = document.getElementById('before').value.
    replace(/\(.+?\)/g, '').
    replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, '+');

  document.getElementById('after').value = str;
}

document.getElementById('replacem').onclick = replacer;
```

```html
<p>Before:
  <input id="before" value="Durarara!!x2 Ten" />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" value="replace" id="replacem" />
</p>

<p>After:
  <input id="after" value="" readonly />
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost there, just one question, this replaces parenthesis with a plus symbol also, such as: Arslan Senki (TV) into Arslan+Senki++TV+, is there a way it can not add the + but instead remove "(TV)" altogether?

I've never been that great with regex, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Before the above replacement, add another line: `str = str.replace(/\(.+?\)/g, '');`

Comment: This is the best answer, I modified the second regex to be `/\.|\(.+?\)/g` to remove the periods/full-stops as well, should have mentioned it, my bad! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

```
 str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
 str  = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9+]/g, "");
```

- First line replaces all the spaces with + symbol
- Second line removes all the non-alphanumeric and non '+' symbols.

Comment: That would remove all non-alphanumeric chars in the first line. Nothing left to replace with + in the second line.

Comment: It'd be Super Awesome if you could describe your approach in addition to the code you post. :)

Comment: OP wants to replace every occurrence of space or non-alphanumeric symbol with JUST ONE '+' sign....durarara+x2+ten is desired result....